# Flutter Navigator.push keeps rebuilding the widget

Tags: flutter

I have 2 Widgets:

1. Widget1.dart (Stateful Widget)
2. test.dart

On Tap of a List Tile in Widget1, I am navigating to test.dart. Here, test.dart keeps rebuilding continuously. I cant seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

This is where I am calling Widget1

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:vts_mobile_cloud/models/call.dart';
import 'package:vts_mobile_cloud/providers/storage_company_provider.dart';
import 'package:vts_mobile_cloud/widgets/widget1.dart';
import '../widgets/call_add.dart';
import '../providers/relationTowCustomer_provider.dart';
import '../providers/processTowedVehicle_provider.dart';
import '../providers/storage_company_provider.dart';

class AddCallScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/add-call';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("add call screen");
    return Widget1();
  }
}

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:vts_mobile_cloud/widgets/test.dart';

class Widget1 extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _Widget1State();
  }
}

class _Widget1State extends State<Widget1> {
  var _towCustomerController = new TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Widget 1 build");
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Add Call"),
    ),
    body: new ListTile(
      title: new TextFormField(
          controller: this._towCustomerController,
          decoration: new InputDecoration(
            labelText: "Customer *",
            suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
          ),
          validator: (value) {
            if (value.isEmpty) {
              return 'Please select Customer';
            }
          },
          onSaved: (val) {
            setState(() {
              //_call.towCustomerName = val;
            });
            // setState(() =>
          },
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
                context,
                new MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => new TestWidget()));
          }
      ),
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

test.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestWidget extends StatefulWidget{

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _TestWidgetState();
  }

}
class _TestWidgetState extends State<TestWidget> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("In Test Widget");
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
      body:Text("Modal")
    );
  }
}
```

It keeps printing "In Test Widget" continuously. Why is it constantly rebuilding the test widget? What is it that I am doing wrong here. It used to work well a few days ago until an update.

Comment: in my case it's calling only once, what r the other things you are doing along with this?

Comment: I have updated my code to show you where I am calling Widget1

Comment: Call me dumb, but why is widget1 a child parameter in a MultiProvider? I've never seen/ implemented one that way...

Comment: Where you are using Provider? or can you just remove MultiProvider and check if it is working for you?

Comment: Ok, so i removed the MultiProvider. Updated the code. It still behaves the same way.